# mySql Index for timestamp date

Tags: mysql, performance, indexing

I have a timestamp column and I have to filter by year. My db has about 10000 rows table.

This is my low query:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE DATE_FORMAT(my_timestamap_data, "%Y") = "2018"
```

how can I improve my performance? The best way is create an index?

thank you!

Comment: If you want to know if an index will improve performance, then create one and see

Comment: try `SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE YEAR(my_timestamap_data) = 2018`

Answer (score 1):

Simple index on `my_timestamap_data`:

And then query:

```
SELECT *
FROM my_table
WHERE my_timestamap >= '2018-01-01' and mytimestamap < 2019-01-01
```